# Session metrics generated using spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics doesn't add up to the actual time spent

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've a `@Transactional` method which triggers 2 SQL queries and returns the fetched objects.
I've enabled the session metrics logging by setting `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true`.
I've also defined a profiler which logs the time taken by the `@Transactional` method, something like this:

```
public Object controllerMethod() {
    var startTime = System.nanoTime();
    var obj = service.transactionalServiceMethod();
    var endTime = System.nanoTime();

    log.info("Time taken: {}", endTime - startTime);

    return obj;
}
```

However the time logged by adding all components of session metrics(1 second) is very less as compared to the time logged by this profiler(6 seconds). I found this unexpected as the service method only triggers 2 SQL queries and returns the object, nothing else. Shouldn't the session metrics time add up to the profiler time? What could be the other possible things which can take additional time which is not captured inside session metrics?